# Visio missing paper background

Tags: microsoft-visio

I've just moved my copy of Visio 2000 from my old Windows XP machine to the new Windows 8.1 machine. When I open a new Visio document on the new machine the whole of the Visio drawing window is white - with a grid if I select it.

This white area extends far beyond the actual size of the paper selected, as indicated by the ruler, from e.g. -20cm to + 20cm. The edges of the paper are not shown. Until I go to 'print preview' I can't see the relationship between the diagram I've drawn and the paper it's to be printed on.

On the XP machine with appropriate zoom level the paper shows white and the 'desktop' on the which the paper rests is shown blue. So I can layout the diagram with reference to the eventual edges of the paper.

Answer (score 0):

This is the cause of it:

https://support.microsoft.com/kb/2993651

I have no idea if it is fixable, apart from uninstalling this update.